# My car randomly won’t start

Tags: ford, starting, mustang

Don’t know if my transponder is going out in my key or if it’s a fuse can some one help. When I try to start the car the millage area goes from numbers to dashes - - and the starter never turns.

Comment: Its a 2005 mustang. With the transponder key. Sometimes it starts and sometimes it doesn’t

Comment: Check engine light on?  What are the stored On Board Diagnosis (OBD) codes?

Comment: From what you're stating, it sounds like the battery is at fault. I'd check the voltage there first, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an issue with your PCM or instrument cluster cutting out. The ----- on ford odometers happens when the IC and PCM are not communicating with each other. Since the pcm and ic are not on speaking terms your immobilizer is activated which will not allow your starter, fuel supply or coils to function. Considering its an intermittent problem I would first check connector harness and wiring for the pcm and ic. Its probably just a loose connector or poor ground somewhere.

It could also be as @Paulster2 suggests, a bad battery or battery connection not supplying enough power to the pcm/ic internals. They do not work well with much lower then 12V.